# installing sqlite3 for ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I've installed the latest version of ruby and mysql but still when i try and run something through aptana with 'requires 'rubygems' and 'requires 'sqlite3' i get the following appear in the console:

```
/home/carladessi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (LoadError)
from /home/carladessi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'from /home/carladessi/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Test/rubydb.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What if you run it in the terminal?

Comment: it doesn't run, it doesn't recognise the fact mysql is installed.

Comment: Did you install mysql server? You also need a mysql gem. Or, better, mysql2. Just run `gem install mysql2`.

Comment: i lied, its sqlite3 not mysql.. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted is for sqlite3 and not MySQL. I've not used Apatana Studio bit it looks as if it, or your program is requesting sqlite3, not MySQL. Check your Gemfile, if you have one, for sqlite3. Also check Apatana Studio requirements to see if it requires sqlite3.

**Updated to reflect change in question:**

It looks as though you're using RVM. Try the following from the terminal.

1.If you are using a `Gemfile` and `bundler` then on the terminal ensure you're executing your application with `bundle exec`. For instance:

```
bundle exec myapp.rb
```

1. Make sure that you are using the same gemset to which you installed sqlite3 with `gem install sqlite`.

Comment: sorry, my fault, you're right it is sqlite3! i've tried so many i forget!